# Toggle Rotate Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an arrow image in a navigation list. I want a code that when it's clicked it'll rotate 90 degrees clockwise downward, and if it's clicked again it'll rotate back to it's original position. I know it's an easy task but I sort of forgot about CSS3/Script relationship.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: you know about toggleclass, if yes please use it and use in css transform: rotate(90deg);

Comment: i see you haven't accepted an answer yet. you can accept an answer by clicking the tick that appears when you hover beside the answer,

Answer (score 1):

This will rotate an image by 90 degrees until it has come full circle

```js
var angle = 0, img = document.getElementById('image');
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
    angle = (angle+90)%360;
    img.className = "rotate"+angle;
}
```

```css
#image {
    transform-origin: top left; /* IE 10+, Firefox, etc. */
    -webkit-transform-origin: top left; /* Chrome */
    -ms-transform-origin: top left; /* IE 9 */
}
#image.rotate90 {
    transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100%);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100%);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100%);
}
#image.rotate180 {
    transform: rotate(180deg) translate(-100%,-100%);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(-100%,-100%);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(-100%,-100%);
}
#image.rotate270 {
    transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100%);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100%);
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100%);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Click me!</button>
<img src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/autumntrees.jpg" width="300" height="auto" id="image" />
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/48qgbg9x/

Answer (score 0):

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/BooXPJ

@Rachel Thank you for that JS bit, i have learned something from that.

However when it comes to rotating elements, i would always go with CSS, and add class on trigger event, it's let code, the above does what the original poster wants with few lines, i have added the toggleClass and given a transform to make it look smooth. And lol, displaying the button "block", so the image does not hide it when rotate.

```
.rotate { -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
-moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
-o-transition-duration:0.5s;width="300" height="auto" id="image"}
```

.rotateclick {transform:rotate(90deg);}

## button {display:block;}

Answer (score -2):

You can use JS to change codes in CSS or HTML (using `<style>`) I believe.

If you know how to rotate the image by using CSS you should be good.

So when user clicks arrow, you change the CSS for the image